# How can I put a counter in my Flutter application that increases everyday a user opens the application?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to put a counter in my application that counts the number of consecutive days a user has opened the application.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.
1.Using the shared preferences package to store the current state of the counter .
2. Or by using any database(firebase preferred) to store user data whenever it logs in user will gets it data back.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can you `shared_preferences` package..and using it..

Keep a flag to check if it is the first time user visiting the app..

Like.. `initialVisit`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await 
 SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final initialvisit = sharedPreferences.getInt("initialvisit") ?? 0;
```

Whenever user opens the app..check if it is the `initialVisit` and based on that..

If it is the initial visit..then store the current date as a string..

If it is not a initial visit, get the existing date and check it with the current date..if the existing date is the previous day..then increment your counter. otherwise..you can reset your counter to `0` again..

You can get more information about `shared_preferences` from their documentation.

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: How do I do it if I link it to a button?
For eg. I want the counter to increase everyday the user clicks on the 'Begin' button.

Comment: Just add the logic inside the `onPressed` function.. something like this..  `_incrementCounter() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
  print('Pressed $counter times.');
  await prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
}` and call this function when button is pressed.. like.. `onPressed: _incrementCounter`..hope it solves your issue..for more info check the plugin documentation.

Comment: But what if the user presses the button more than once in 1 day? Won't that make the counter increment it's value?

Comment: You have to write custom code for that..like have some `bool` and..in the `initState` check for the date that you stored lastly with `shared_preferences` if that date is not today then initialise it with `true` and `false` otherwise..also..coming to displaying the button..show the button only if the `bool` is true..along with that..if the button is being displayed..then, `setState` the `bool` to `false` once user taps that, before calling the `incrementCounter` function.

Comment: `onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => FourthRoute()),
                  );}`
This is the code for **onPressed** could you please edit it with the solution?

Comment: Srikanth this is actually for my project that I have to submit in a few days. I was wondering if you could help me out better if you could have a look at the full app code because there is a ML model that I want to implement in my app. Can I contact you on twi tter?

Comment: Please accept the follow request so I can message you.

Comment: *please follow me back